# why cannot i see a textView above another view in relative layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/pointsText"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

                <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/offers_list"
        android:text="you have 100 points"
        android:visibility="visible"/>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/offers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="#00000000"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Yet I cannot see pointsText in my eclipse graphical previewer.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
android:layout_above="@+id/offers_list"
```

for your `TextView` but you don't have any positioning for your `ListView`. Since `RelativeLayout`s place their children at the top-left by default, your `ListView` would be at the top and there would be nowhere above it to place your `TextView`.

Try removing that property from your `TextView` and add

```
android:layout_below="@id/pointsText"
```

on your `ListView`.

I just tested this and it does work. I can see the pointsText  `TextView` above the list. So, you will want to do something different with your error `TextView` or you will quite possibly have the same issue with that when you want to change its `visibility`.

**A bit off-topic**

`RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property so that doesn't do you any good but doesn't do you any real harm either.

Answer (score 0):

When you use relative layouts, layout elements lay upon each other. To prevent that you should place element Relatively to other layouts. make your code like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/pointsText"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/offers_list"
        android:text="you have 100 points"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/errorMsg"/>



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/offers_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pointsText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you will be able to see your all layouts

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="you have 100 points"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/offers_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a fragment inside an activity, you may want to check the nesting of say, the AppBarLayout and the layout into which you add the fragment